# Can I use these both tenses (past simple and present perfect) in this sentence

Tags: past-tense

I ordered a book through the net and was waiting to receive it. Today it came at last.
Shall I say once I have opened my mailbox and taken the book.

> I have waited for a long time but it came at last .

OR can I use the simple past because the wait is over? I have received the book.

> I waited for a long time but it came at last .

Or are both ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither of them is correct for the context you give.

The waiting part happens *before* the coming part, so it makes no sense that "wait" should be in a present tense (present perfect *is* a present tense), and "come" in the simple past.

If you're happy *now* that a long-awaited package has arrived, you should use a present tense to describe its arrival:

And since waiting for your package is finished, the most natural way is to use the simple past. So..

> I ***waited*** for a long time, but it ***has come*** at last.

Comment: could you let me know if "I have waited for a long time but it has come at last " would be possible as present perfect can indicate that the action has recently finished and that is the case here

Comment: @user5577 Yes, that would be fine.